# Why after dd'ing ISO file to entire USB flash device, only the first partition match the ISO checksum?

Tags: linux, usb-drive, boot, uefi, disk-image

I use dd to "burn" an ISO file to USB stick:

```
dd bs=4M if=/mnt/media/ISO/Fedora-Workstation-Live-x86_64-31-1.9.iso   of=/dev/sdd conv=fdatasync  status=progress
```

Now I can see several partitions has been created:

```
sdd      8:48   1   1.9G  0 disk 
├─sdd1   8:49   1   1.8G  0 part /run/media/alex/Fedora-WS-Live-31-1-9
├─sdd2   8:50   1  10.6M  0 part 
└─sdd3   8:51   1  22.2M  0 part
```

Why only sdd1 matches the ISO checksum, not an entire drive? I checked files on other partitions, they contain this ISO related files..

Comment: I also have a message "check the media" has failed, it's not recommended to use this media...

Comment: why it's off-topic it's a security question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It's not clear to me what you are trying to accomplish.**

You appear to be writing a *file* to a *raw device*. Unless the file is a disk image appropriate for that kind of device, this makes no sense to me.

The Fedora-Live ISO is a SquashFS file system, not a binary or raw image suitable for dumping to a raw device.

Since this is a Fedora-Live ISO, I'm guessing that you want to create a bootable USB vice the bootable DvD you'd get from simply burning the ISO to a DVD. There are standard tools for doing that such as: [Unetbootin](http://unetbootin.github.io/)

```
          ****** edit *****
```

OK, I pulled down the ISO file and did an **fdisk** of the ISO.

> fdisk Fedora-Workstation-Live-x86_64-31-1.9.iso
>
> Command (m for help): p
>
> Disk  Fedora-Workstation-Live-x86_64-31-1.9.iso: 1.8 GiB, 1929379840
>   bytes, 3768320 sectors Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes  Sector
>   size  (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes  I/O size
>   (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes  Disklabel type: dos  Disk
>   identifier: 0x6f869649
>
> Device                                     Boot Start     End Sectors 
>   Size Id Type
>
> Fedora-Workstation-Live-x86_64-31-1.9.iso1 *        0 3768319 3768320 
>   1.8G  0 Empty
>
> Fedora-Workstation-Live-x86_64-31-1.9.iso2        172   21887   21716
>   10.6M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)
>
> Fedora-Workstation-Live-x86_64-31-1.9.iso3      888   67407   45520
>   22.2M  0 Empty

**The ISO defines 3 partitions of which 1 & 3 are *Type 0 Empty*.**

Comment: I am comparing the checksums of ISO and /dev/sdd, and they don't match, that's the issue. However /dev/sdd1 does match, which is surprising to me. About whether this method of creating a bootable device works, it'll test and let you know, thanks

Comment: This is useful, thank you. If they are empty, why do I see some EFI files when I mount them?

Comment: They are not _empty_ they are **Partition Type 0 Empty**. Partition type 6 is _FAT16_ and type 7 is HPFS/NTFS/exFAT. I don't know why it's called "Empty".

Answer (score 1):

DD copies the image byte by byte onto the USB drive, It creates an exact clone.It creates one partition that holds the image, that's why only the partition that contains the image file has a matching checksum. I'm not entirely sure about the particulars of Fedora but, In typical Linux Distributions when DD command is used to create a bootable USB drive, the two partitions are:

1. The partition that contains the Image (checksum match)
2. The EFI partition (contains file required to boot your os, link=https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_system_partition).

The remaining space on the drive is left as Unallocated free space.
If you provide more details about the files in the other partitions, I might be able to give a better answer

Comment: okay thanks for the input, but what about the nest two partitions, where they came from, why contain Fefora-31 related files?

Answer (score 0):

Unless /dev/sdd is exactly the same size of the ISO file (which is unlikely), then /dev/sdd will contain unallocated empty spaces which contains either old deleted data or zeros. Even if they contain zeros, they will still affect the checksum.

You may have to use `head -c <number of bytes> /dev/sdd` when reading from /dev/sdd to remove the padding at the end of the device when calculating its checksum.

Comment: This is also useful, thank you, at first they didn't match, maybe I mounted as `rw` and something changed, I ran dd again, and now the checksum match, however it's still not clear why sdd1 matches, if there are some EFI  files on "empty" partitions...